# migrate template from velocity to freemarker

Tags: java, templates, liferay, freemarker, velocity

I need to migrate some templates from velocity in liferay 6.2 to freemarker for liferay 7.4 dxp, I tried to use the USCavalry tool, but the result is not complete, can someone help me?
this is an example of the results I get with the tool I mentioned, when I try to test a template I get several errors.

````
<#assign layoutId = request.get("theme-display").get("plid")>
<#-- get the service for layout-->
<#assign layoutService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.LayoutLocalService")>
<#--convert the layout id into long-->
<#assign layoutLong = getterUtil.getLong(layoutId)>
<#--take a layout object-->
<#assign layout = layoutService.getLayout(layoutLong)><#assign pageName = layout.getName(locale)>
<#if layout.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("isTabPage") == false>    
        <h1 id="genericPageTitle">
                <span class="webContentPageTitle">${pageName}</span>
        </h1>
</#if>
<#-- get Date object-->
<#assign modDate = dateTool.toDate("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z", reserved-article-modified-date.data, locale)>
<#-- get format Date-->
<#assign modDateFormat = dateTool.format("yyyy/MM/dd", modDate, locale)><#assign paramName = "error">
<#assign errorToShow = httpUtil.getParameter(request.get("attributes").CURRENT_COMPLETE_URL, paramName)>
<div class="webContentModifiedDate <#if layout.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute('isTabPage') == true> webContentModifiedDateTapPage </#if>">
        <div class="webContentPrint" onclick="printElem('webContentMainDiv');"></div> 
</div>
<div id="webContentMainDiv" class="webContentMainDiv">

        <div class="portlet-msg-error">
        ${languageUtil.get(locale, errorKey.getData())}<br/>
                <#if errorToShow != "">
                        <div id="portlet-msg-error-detail" style="margin-top:30px;">
                                ${languageUtil.get(locale, "error.details")}<br/>
                                <b>
                                        <i>${httpUtil.decodeURL(errorToShow)}<i>
                                </b>
                        </div>
                </#if>
        </div>
</div>```
````

Comment: Rewrite by hand, it's quicker

Comment: It's okay, it's true. But can you tell me if the first lines are correct? I'm not sure how to make those service calls in 7.4

Comment: Quite a lot of stuff has changed since 2013 (the original release year of 6.2) - many features that were usually solved through templates have simpler, more elegant and easier to maintain solutions today. I'd say: Start with "what do you want to achieve?", then check how else you could implement it today. E.g. * what did you use the "tabPages" for? * is there a solution, e.g. through Master Pages today?

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation, clearly I still have a lot to learn about liferay, I am very new and I went to fall into a migration project so there is much that I still do not know about this technology and also about its versions.

Answer (score 0):

USCavalry is ancient. You have to do most of the work by hand, sorry.

Comment: It's what I thought. So I should change my question pointing to the public that knows liferay so that they help me modify these lines that are the most difficult so far, I must clarify that I am a very beginner in liferay.